# Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference (Android)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I'm trying to make a mini mobile wallet which stores users' details on firebase. I'm getting the error

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.TextView.setText(int)' on a null object reference

while using the setText() method to show user's balance. I've referred to many other similar questions on stackoverflow, but nothing helped me out.

Here are code files I think I have problem with.

> The below code if for a fragment (wallet_info.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         tools:context=".PassBook">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<TextView
    android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:id="@+id/walletText"
    android:text="Wallet Balance"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_margin="30dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/walletText"
    android:id="@+id/balanceText"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/balanceText"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:text="Request Balance"
    android:onClick="onRequest"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

The `android:onClick="onRequest"` shows a red underline asking me to create a public method even though I've created the method in the class on which the fragment is attached.

> The below code is for home.java (a class on which wallet_info.xml fragment is attached.) I'm pasting the part where I'm getting the error.

```
public void onRequest(View view){
    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.balanceText);
    wallet.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            wallet_info u = dataSnapshot.child(m).getValue(wallet_info.class);
            tv.setText(u.getBalance());
            //tv.setText(u.getBalance());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

The line `tv.setText(u.getBalance());` throws the mentioned error.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though questions like this on stackoverflow didn't have the answer I needed, I came up with the solution. I don't know why it shows a NULL POINTER EXCEPTION even when I created an object of TextView. The error got solved by changing the data type of parameter in setText() to string.

The problem got resolved after changing the code as follows.

```
wallet_info u = dataSnapshot.child(m).getValue(wallet_info.class);
tv.setText(u.getBalance());
```

The above lines of code were changed to -

```
wallet_info u = dataSnapshot.child(m).getValue(wallet_info.class);
g = String.valueOf(u.getBalance());
tv.setText(g);
```

This solved my problem.

Comment: Yeah, the `TextView#setText(int)` method expects that the int passed is a string resource id like R.string.string_name.  That's a pretty wild error message if that was the only problem, though.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you can't use the following attribute:

```
android:onClick="onRequest"
```

inside a layout for a Fragment. It's only work for an Activity. Hence, you need to bind the `balanceText` view and create the `View.onClickListener` for `button2` button.